# iPhone App how to post Youtube video link using facebook graph Api

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, facebook-graph-api

in iPhone App how to post Youtube video link  using facebook graph Api to FaceBook Wall post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
-(IBAction)postMeFeedButtonPressed:(id)sender {

NSMutableDictionary *variables = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:4];

[variables setObject:@"#Your Message" forKey:@"message"];
[variables setObject:@"#http://Your Youtube Link" forKey:@"link"];
[variables setObject:@"#This is the bolded copy next to the image" forKey:@"name"];
[variables setObject:@"#This is the plain text copy next to the image.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy." forKey:@"description"];


FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphPost:@"me/feed" withPostVars:variables];
NSLog(@"postMeFeedButtonPressed:  %@", fb_graph_response.htmlResponse);

//parse our json
SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
NSDictionary *facebook_response = [parser objectWithString:fb_graph_response.htmlResponse error:nil];   
[parser release];

//let's save the 'id' Facebook gives us so we can delete it if the user presses the 'delete /me/feed button'
self.feedPostId = (NSString *)[facebook_response objectForKey:@"id"];
NSLog(@"feedPostId, %@", feedPostId);
NSLog(@"Now log into Facebook and look at your profile...");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to post youtube video

```
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];
    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:@{ACFacebookAppIdKey : facebookAppKey, ACFacebookPermissionsKey : [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_stream", nil], ACFacebookAudienceKey : ACFacebookAudienceOnlyMe} completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if(granted ) {

            NSArray  *accountsArray = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
            NSDictionary *postDict = @{
                                       @"link": youtubeurl,//URL of youtube video 
                                     };
            ACAccount *facebookAccount = [accountsArray objectAtIndex:0];
            SLRequest *facebookRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                                            requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                                                                      URL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed"]
                                                               parameters:postDict];

            [facebookRequest setAccount:facebookAccount];

            [facebookRequest performRequestWithHandler:^( NSData* responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse* urlResponse, NSError* error ) {

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                    [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:true];
                    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Posted Successfully on Facebook" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                    [alert show];
                });
            }];

        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error %@", error.description);
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Account not found" message:@"Please log in to Facebook account from Settings" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                [alert show];
            });
        }
    }];
```